# Unable to share question in WhatsApp

Tags: bug, android-app

I am unable to share a question that I posted on movies.stackexchange via WhatsApp. I am using the share icon in the question card.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: Motorola
- Device Model: Moto G (4)

  - OS Version: 7.0 (16)

Comment: Do you get an error message or so?

Comment: No I didn't. Once I select whatsapp contact to which I want to share the link,no matter how many times I tap the send button, nothing happens

Comment: And this isn't a bug with WhatsApp?

Comment: I can share other links alright. That's weird

Comment: [No repro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVPOh.png).